# Err: Type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; ...' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

i'm trying to add the list of user to array, where it throws above mentioned **error**

```
export interface User{
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    age:number;
    address:{
        street:string,
        city:string,
        state:string
    }
}
```

this is my interface

and here i'm trying to add the user which is of type user[]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../models/User';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  //Properties
  users :User[];

  //Methods
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.users[
    {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: 30,
      address : {
        street: "3rd Cross",
        city: "Bangalore",
        state: "Karnataka"
      }
    }
   ];

  }

}
```

can anyone explain where did i have made error please.
[Program Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cv6w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code should be -

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.users = [
    {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: 30,
      address : {
        street: "3rd Cross",
        city: "Bangalore",
        state: "Karnataka"
      }
    }
   ];

  }
```

As explained in error you are not setting the value to the variable. instead, you are trying to add value as an index of the array which is wrong formatted.